# Determining Which Web Font Is Rendered In Chrome

Tags: html, css, fonts

I know that this has been asked many times before, but I could neither find a satisfactory answer, nor a post less than 2 years old.

My question is for development purposes, and I want to be able to tell which font is actually being rendered.

I am aware of the 'computed style' tab.  However, if I select an element, and set `font-family:dsfsafsd`, then what shows up in computed styles for font-family is `dsfsafsd`.

When I'm testing several web fonts, it is often difficult to know if I entered the name incorrectly, and it is showing my default font, or if it just looks like that, or if I have cascading rules and it is showing a font that is somewhere in the stack.

I find it very difficult to positively visually identify font - particularly with different sizes, colors, styles, and backgrounds.  Otherwise, I could just look at it and think, *Oh..hey, that's `Times New Roman`.  I must be doing something wrong.*  (I actually do think in **Markdown**).

But as it stands, when working with fonts that look similar; I can't be absolutely sure whether it's the default font being displayed or if that's just how the font in question looks.  Ultimately, I just go with what looks good; but it'd be nice to know what is being displayed when hacking around in Dev Tools and changing the font 10 times in 10 minutes.

Any current workable solutions to this problem?

Comment: I use WhatFont plug in https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en

Comment: It's not clear why looking in computed styles isn't a good solution to your issue.

Comment: @sphanley.  `I am aware of the 'computed style' tab. However, if I select an element, and set font-family:dsfsafsd, then what shows up in computed styles for font-family is dsfsafsd.`  There is no font-family named *dsfsafsd*.  In other words - it shows what value is being applied by my CSS; not what value is actually rendered.  So in reality it is something like `Arial` or `Times New Roman`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following chrome extension:
[WhatFont](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm/related?hl=en)

[image: WhatFont Screenshot]

or you can also check Computed Styles in Chrome's Inspector
[image: Computed Styles in Chrome's Inspector]

Comment: from my post:  `If I select an element, and set font-family:dsfsafsd, then what shows up in computed styles for font-family is dsfsafsd.`  It's not a reliable measure for what is actually being used - which is likely `Arial` or `Times New Roman`.  With WhatFont:  it showed me pages that are using Helvetica as Helvetica.  That can't be right can it?  I have a PC.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Whatfont  does what I want. Very helpful.  I still don't get why Helvetica shows sometimes on my Windows box though